# How to properly know from which edge a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer comes from?

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` on left and right edges of the screen.

So far, to know from which edge the pan is coming from, I based it on the translation. If it is < 0, it comes from the right edge, if it is > 0 it comes from the left edge.

But in landscape, I realized that if for example you start panning from the right edge to the left (translation < 0) and then come back to the right edge and keep panning out of the screen, then the translation becomes positive at a point.

I thought to affect a variable in `UIGestureRecognizerState.Began` and check it in `UIGestureRecognizerState.End` instead of the translation but I'm not sure it is the best way.

So my question: what is the best way to check from where comes the screen edge pan?

Comment: Can't you just get the location of the touch in the view then deduce it from there?

Comment: yes probably, but then it is about the same than affecting a boolean in .Began. I am just wondering if there is a proper way to find it, something more "official" than a custom way but maybe I'm just wrong and getting the location of the touch or using a variable are good ways to do it...

Comment: No it's not a part of the API so I'm afraid you are going to need to write a bit of state. If you are against a Boolean just keep track of the point .Began occurred and derive the location from there/)

Comment: @DanielGalasko Using `locationInView` seems to not be the best as I managed to have it returned this value (644.0, 196.5) while being in `UIGestureRecognizerState.Began`. And it seems as well than basing the solution on the translation might not be working all the time either. I don't know if it's a bug yet or not, but in landscape I realised that with a quick enough pan, in the half lower part of the phone (whatever the landscape is), the translation is (0.0, 0.0) in `.Began`. And it's the same for both direction, which makes it impossible to find out the direction while being in `.Began`

Comment: Here is the link of the topic I just created. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553186. I guess I will have to use two different targets, one for each gesture