# translationInView equal to 0 when fast panning using UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I created a test [project](https://github.com/nico75005/TestQuickLowerSpanInLandscape) showing the problem.

When I do a fast pan from the left or right edge, during the state `UIGestureRecognizerState.Began`, the `translationInView` is equal to (0.0, 0.0). This happens when you are in `landscape` and do the gesture in the lower half of the device (iphone 6 in my case) or when you are in `portrait`and do the gesture in about the 1rst third part of the screen (from the bottom).

Is it... normal? I guess it's probably know but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.  The value returned by `translationInView(_:)` is relative to the first point where the gesture began, which makes sense during the `.Began` because that is immediately after that first point is established.

Also, just want to make sure you understand that you are using `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` and not some other `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.  The normal behavior of `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` is to only be active near the screen edges, which explains the active areas you are describing.  Since you mention it, just want to make sure there's no confusion (please person me if that's not the case).

Comment: Yes I know we are talking about `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`. And it would make sense indeed (at least for me) that the first translation would be x=0. But when I make a slow pan, the translation is never 0 (it gets to x=0.5 when I'm moving it really slowly). And why the behaviour is different depending where you start on the y axis?

Comment: Happening for me as well, in portrait mode, regardless of screen position edge pan. Same code was working some time ago, but now I see that translation returns 0 when you move finger fast. Looking for solution. Will post here if I find something

Comment: I can not locate your test project on GitHub, btw, so not sure if your case is similar to mine.
I fixed my issue: the problem was in my custom transition manager. After I return self from interactionControllerForPresentation I started getting non-zero translation(in: ) for the gesture. Otherwise transition coordinator ignores gesture and simply animates transition. Let me know if you have same issue and I will post my comment as answer.